# Hide.me: Unable to connect from a PC to another via Windows remote desktop

Tags: vpn, windows-7, remote-desktop, pptp

Now I have two Win7-devices connected via hide.me VPN. Both are successfully connected to the VPN 
Both devices are registered with the same reserved IP in the same server.
The problem is that I cannot connect them via remote desktop in Win7.

When I ping from one PC to another they cannot see each other.
One has as a IP 10.3.AA.BB.
The other one has a IP 10.3.XX.YY.

what is the problem? how can I solve it in order to both stay in the same network? is that possible?
Thanks

Comment: IP addresses mean nothing without their accompanying subnet masks. Please edit your question with that information. Also, You are using a workstation OS as a server, which is not going to end well.

Comment: @EEAA but I understood that hide.me is my vpn server? the two windows PC's are clients... why do you say that is not going to end well?

Comment: You are connecting from one client to another, so one of them is providing server roles, which is not an appropriate usage of a client operating system.

Comment: @EEAA my sorry. I mean I have two Pc's connected into a VPN. I'0m using hide.me as a vpn server provider. Both PC's are clients of that VPN server.

Comment: Yep, and if you're trying to connect from one PC to the other, that means you're using one of them as a server.